# Create Sub Headers in R

Tags: r

I'd like to create a df that has a header and a subheader. Example below:

I want to take the following input:

```
input <- tibble::tribble(
             ~Region,  ~Day_1, ~Day_2,  ~Day_3,
           "Central",  "Boat",     NA,      NA,
           "Central",      NA, "Shoe",      NA,
           "Central",      NA,     NA, "Table",
           "Pacific",      NA, "Boat",      NA,
           "Pacific", "Table",     NA,      NA,
           "Pacific",      NA,     NA,  "Shoe",
           "Eastern",  "Boat",     NA,      NA,
           "Eastern",      NA, "Shoe",      NA,
           "Eastern",      NA,     NA, "Table",
           "Eastern", "Watch",     NA,      NA,
           "Eastern", "Chair",     NA,      NA,
           "Eastern",      NA,  "Cup",      NA
           )
```

and convert it to the following output:

```
  Central Central Central Pacific Pacific Pacific Eastern Eastern Eastern
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 Day_1   Day_2   Day_3   Day_1   Day_2   Day_3   Day_1   Day_2   Day_3  
2 Boat    Shoe    Table   Table   Boat    Shoe    Boat    Shoe    Table  
3 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      Watch   Cup     NA     
4 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      Chair   NA      NA
```

Any thoughts?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: where did you get `Watch, Chair, Cup` etc from?? They are not in the original table given

Comment: Sorry!  Updated the input df

Comment: R does not do sub-headers, column names are a singular thing. If you mean for rendering (report generation), then it is feasible with some fancy-table generators (perhaps `gt` or `kableExtra` to list two of several), but not in a usable-data kind of way.

Comment: You have cup but no shoe. You need to include shoe Eastern Day 2

Comment: @Onyambu it should be there, it's the 8th row down!  Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for that information.  I am trying to render a final report but wasn't sure if R could produce an output df like this.

Comment: sschade, I understand, in which case look into the table "finishers", so to speak. `gt` and `kableExtra` are two, I think `stargazer` might work, I'm sure there are others. They will all avoid the "flaw" of doing it in raw R in that the row numbers are correct (in Onyambu's excellent answer, row number 1 is technically not data ... misleading and an OCD-level issue, to be sure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

input %>%
  pivot_longer(-Region) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(Region, name) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = value) %>%
  data.table::transpose(make.names = TRUE)
  
  Central Central Central Pacific Pacific Pacific Eastern Eastern Eastern
1   Day_1   Day_2   Day_3   Day_2   Day_1   Day_3   Day_1   Day_2   Day_3
2    Boat    Shoe   Table    Boat   Table    Shoe    Boat    Shoe   Table
3    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   Watch     Cup    <NA>
4    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   Chair    <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: Is there a way to arrange the Region so they are grouped together?  And also to make the the 'name' stays in order from Day_1, Day_2, and Day_3?  Thanks!